# Need to point to hidden div

Tags: jquery, tabs, location

I'm new to programming and am really trying to understand what's going on in my code, but as with anything, it takes time. I know this might be blatantly obvious with someone to experience, but I can't figure out how to do it... I've been using Duckett's javascript book as a reference and guide. This code is borrowed from him.

I need to be able to reference and display each panel. I've tried referencing the index.html#tab-1 etc. I'm not sure how to additionally set a location so that it could be pointed to. The redundant way is to create new pages for each panel, but I want the content to be dynamic and the file structre clean. Please help.

[Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/whoispoppe/pen/xbGwQO)

Html structure:

```
   <ul class="tab-list">
      <li class="active"><a class="tab-control" href="#tab-1">Mission &amp; Vision</a></li>
      <li><a class="tab-control" href="#tab-2">Facilities &amp; Services</a></li>
      <li><a class="tab-control" href="#tab-3">Policies</a></li>
      <li><a class="tab-control" href="#tab-4">History</a></li>
    </ul>

  <div class="tab-panel active" id ="tab-1">
    <p> Content etc. </p>

  <div class="tab-panel active" id ="tab-2">
    <p> Content etc. </p>

  <div class="tab-panel active" id ="tab-3">
    <p> Content etc. </p>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.tab-list').each(function(){                   // Find lists of tabs
var $this = $(this),                            // Store this list
  $tab = $this.find('li.active'),             // Get the active list item
  $link = $tab.find('a'),                     // Get link from active tab
  $panel = $($link.attr('href'));             // Get active panel

$this.on('click', '.tab-control', function(e) { // When click on a tab
e.preventDefault();                           // Prevent link behavior
var $link = $(this),                          // Store the current link
    id = this.hash;                           // Get href of clicked tab 

if (id && !$link.is('.active')) {             // If not currently active
  $panel.removeClass('active');               // Make panel inactive
  $tab.removeClass('active');                 // Make tab inactive

  $panel = $(id).addClass('active');          // Make new panel active
  $tab = $link.parent().addClass('active');   // Make new tab active 
  }
 });
 });
```

Comment: It may just be me but this seems like a lot to digest for what sounds like a simple jQuery problem. Can you show us the lines of code that are not behaving as you'd expect please? Specifically, what are you trying to achieve? What do you mean be `set a location so that it could be pointed to`?

Comment: It kinda sounds like you are trying to create template pages? If you want to make 'slides' that can be created dynamically, along with content, it would do you good to learn PHP.

Comment: Php is the next step most definitely. Here is what I need to happen:

1. User has url link to panel  content ex. index.html#tab-1
2. When user goes to link tab-1 opens

I can't get this to happen with the way it is currently coded because of preventing Default link behavior. However, I'm not sure how to get the tabs to work without doing this

Comment: @DeeMac I might just be overcomplicating the issue. I need to users to be able to navigate to specific sections through a direct link.

Answer (score 0):

Updated codepen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JodKEd#load-tab-2) to work with both internal and exetnal links. (and fixed `.tab-control` click function)

```
$('.tab-list li').on('click', '.tab-control', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    id = this.hash;
    activateTab(id);
});

$("a.direct").on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    id = this.hash;
    activateTab(id);
});

function activateTab(id){
    var li = $("li a[href="+id+"]").parent();
    if (id && !li.is('.active')) { 
        $("li.active").removeClass('active');
        $('.tab-panel').removeClass('active');
        $(id).addClass('active');       
        $("li a[href="+id+"]").parent().addClass("active");
    }
}

if(document.location.hash){
    //if( write_here_some_check_for_valid_hash: #load-tab-x ){
        var hash = document.location.hash.split("-");
        var id = "#"+hash[1]+"-"+hash[2];
        activateTab(id);
    //}
}
```

In external links use `#load-tab-2` hash to load `tab-2`. The `load` prefix in hash is to prevent page auto scrolling.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was a simple fix... Can you explain to me why this works?

Comment: I incorporated it to the live site, http://www.iu.edu/~celt/WebsiteRedesign/test/about/index.html but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you mean? The links in theory are just index.html#tab-1, index.html#tab-2, and so on. I'm imagining part of the problem is that they don't show up in the url when clicked. It's just changed from hidden to displayed.

Comment: iu.edu/~celt/WebsiteRedesign/test/about/index.html#tab-2 doesn't open the Facilities & Services Panel.

Comment: So that's what isn't working. I need the # tags to open up the associated panel when referenced without creating additional pages.